# WebBrowser control mouse events under Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

On Windows Phone 7, do the WebBrowser control mouse events (e.g. [MouseMove, MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)) never fire? I've set breakpoints and they never hit. Is there a way to know when the user interacts with the control?

I'm trying to do [my own idle detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28VS.92%29.aspx) so the phone doesn't lock while the user is reading on a specific view. However, the main part of that view is a WebBrowser control.

Comment: Why do you need to implement your own idle detection? Can't you just ask the user if it's OK to disable idle detection and then your application won't go to sleep while they're reading. That's what the feature is for.

Comment: I'm implementing my own idle detection because I'm turning it off and the docs recommend doing your own if you turn it off so that you don't leave the device unlocked forever. I need the idle time to be longer than normal because we expect the user to be reading extended passages and thus not interacting with the screen. But if they scroll in the WebBrowser control I want to reset my timer that otherwise will enable system idle detection.

Answer (score 1):

The phone doesn't have a mouse!
It uses touch/tap events and so these (mouse related) events have no meaning on the phone.

If you must do this, try using the Manipulation events instead.

Comment: What touch/tap events are you referring to? Can you add a link to MSDN documentation for them?

I know the phone doesn't have a mouse, but on the old Windows Mobile 6 phones with the compact framework the mouse events responded. They are basically an input device events. So I thought they might work. Why does the framework have them if they don't work? (other than they come from the inherited Control class)

Comment: @mikelberger the CF includes lots of things which aren't relevant on the phone. This is due to them sharing the same base class definitions as the full framework. WebBrowser docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser_members(v=VS.92).aspx. If you follow the link to the OnManipulationStarted method it will point you to the article on handling manipulation events on the phone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933(v=vs.95)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @matt. The Manipulation events as well don't seem to be firing for the WebBrowser control. I created a new project and add a WebBrowser control. I then hooked up the ManipulationDelta event for both the page and the WebBrowser. When tapping over any part of the screen that isn't the WebBrowser then the Page's ManipulationDelta event does fire. But when I tap over the WebBrowser neither event fires.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Derek here. If you are just looking to make sure that the phone does not go into lock mode while the user is reading something in your app, the following should work:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Right, I can make the phone not go into lock mode. But per the documentation I linked to, if you turn it off then it is recommended to implement your own idle detection. The other controls raise the mouse events but the WebBrowser control doesn't. If I didn't have a WebBrowser control as the majority of the form I could have each of those controls reset my timer that enables the idle detection.